# How to persist such data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-key-relationship, modeling, table-relationships

I have the following 5 classes [other attributes and methods have been skipped]

**CommonInterface.java**

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class CommonInterface {

        public Vector  myDescription;
        public Vector  myPartyPlaceThing;
        public Vector  myRole;
        public Vector  myMomentInterval;

    }
```

**Description.java**

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Description {

     public Vector  myPartyPlaceThing;
        public Vector  myCommonInterface;

    }
```

**PartyPlaceThing.java**

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class PartyPlaceThing {

      public Vector  myRole;
        public Description myDescription;
        public Vector  myCommonInterface;

    }
```

**Role.java**

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Role {

    public Vector  myMomentInterval;
        public PartyPlaceThing myPartyPlaceThing;
        public Vector  myCommonInterface;

    }
```

**MomentInterval.java**

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class MomentInterval {

    public Role myRole;
    public Vector  myMIDetail;
    public Vector  myCommonInterface;

    }
```

**MIDetail.java**

```
    public class MIDetail {

        public MomentInterval myMomentInterval;

    }
```

Now I want to persist the data in these classes in a database [mysql] where "**tableName in DB == className in java**"

I know that such attributes will be included as foreign keys but the **problem** is how will the tables basically be created?

**e.g** the table description would contain partyplacething as foreign key. This means that table of partyplacething **must** exist before table of description can be created. similar is the case with other classes thus creating a deadlock cuz I need tables of "role and description" before I can create partyplacething and so on. the only table that I can successfully create is of MIDetail (right now cuz it is independent).

**How should I change my model so that my original relationships are maintained and I can successfully persist data in a database???**

Comment: :) no its not homework. i m working on tool development. just the database phase is left. and after evaluation of my classes i found out  that i have this problem with the relationship in classes. i was lost on how to proceed. i looked on internet [2 days] and i just could not find a "spot on" for what i m looking for. that is y i thought about asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jpa and check the jpa tutorials.

Comment: i found the link. actually i needed a suggestion of trying to get out of my deadlock